# Regularity of a domain - definition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

What does it mean when we say that a domain is $C^k$, $C^{k,\alpha}$, Lipschitz, or smooth? Is there an intuitive understanding?

Answer (score 11):

Smooth domain $\Omega$ is an open and connected subset of the whole domain, say $\mathbb{R}^n$, of which the boundary $\partial \Omega$ is "smooth".

The smoothness of the boundary, intuitively speaking, is:

> The boundary of a smooth domain can be viewed as the graph of a smooth function locally.

How smooth this function is determines the smoothness of the boundary. For example, $C^{k,\alpha}$-domain. Formal definition please refer to [Gilbarg and Trudinger's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=eoiGTf4cmhwC) section 6.2. For any point on the boundary of a $C^{k,\alpha}$-domain, the boundary of domain within this point's neighborhood is the graph of a $C^{k,\alpha}$ function of $(n-1)$ variables. To visualize this a bit you could think the domain being in $\mathbb{R}^2$, a domain having $C^{k,\alpha}$ smoothness says each small piece of the boundary is a $C^{k,\alpha}$ function's graph, i.e., a smooth 1 dimension curve.

Another example would be [Lipschitz domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_domain), polygon and polyhedra are Lipschitz domains in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ respectively.

The motivation of formalization of the smooth domain originates from the idea of the estimates measuring how smooth the solution of a boundary value problem is.

Comment: You seem knowledgeable about this topic. Can I ask a quick question? Let $\Omega = (0,1)^2$. Can we say $\Omega$ is $C^{k,\alpha}$ domain for some $k$ and $\alpha$? Intuitively, it is almost $C^{k,\alpha}$ except for the four corner points which seem not smooth. But not sure how to justify it, especially, the construction of the smooth mapping. Thanks.

Comment: @induction601 $(0,1)^2$ is a Lipschitz domain, $C^{0,1}$.

Comment: Sorry for replying to this old post, but is the claim "$\partial\Omega$ is $C^1$" equivalent to the claim "$\partial\Omega$ is a $(d-1)$-dimensional embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$"?